# firing a click event when pressing enter inside a textfield

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

sorry for the questions... but I'm a little stuck again.

I ask these questions so I can get the most out of my time/learning.

I am trying to fire a click event (so when i manually click the login btn) with the enter key.

The code i have so far

**code**

```
 usernameField.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER){
            loginBtn.fire();
            System.out.println("Worked");
        }
    });
```

That does what it's supposed to, almost. the system out message appears but does now fire the loginBtn.

I am using JavaFX and JFXButtons/textboxes if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text fields fire action events when the user presses the enter key. So all you need is

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> loginHandler = e -> {
    // handle login here...
};

usernameTextField.setOnAction(loginHandler);
loginBtn.setOnAction(loginHandler);
```

Or, if you prefer;

```
usernameTextField.setOnAction(e -> handleLogin());
loginBtn.setOnAction(e -> handleLogin());

// ...

private void handleLogin() {
    // handle login here...
}
```

If you are using FXML, you can just map both `onAction` handlers to the same controller method:

```xml
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" onAction="#login" />
<Button fx:id="loginBtn" text="Log In" onAction="#login" />
```

and then in the controller

```
public class Controller {

    // ...

    @FXML
    private void login() {
        // login action here..
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am at work at the moment and I apologise if i seem ignorant or not very knowledgeable but my loginBtn code has a MouseEvent event in it. How would I call this? 

so it would be handLogin(MouseEvent event) {

Comment: @R-Bown Why would you use a mouse listener on a button?

Comment: I'm at work at the moment and don't have the code in front of me. I'll reply to this post later tonight if that's okay? Thanks again James

Comment: Your updated post will actually do the trick. I do indeed use fxml. That's great. Thank you :)